# Mocks for google spreadsheets api

Tags: mocking, pytest, google-sheets-api, google-docs-api, gspread

I'm working on a project that involves storing and manipulating data in Google Sheets, and I'm looking for the best way to test it. I want to ensure that my update requests are working properly. Is it possible to mock Google Sheets and create spreadsheets locally?

The only approach I am aware of involves connecting to real Google Sheets using a testing account for testing purposes, but this can be inefficient due to network requests.